# Removing Multiple words in a string

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm not trying to replace any words, I'm simply trying to remove specific words from the table without eliminating the entire string.
I tried this:

```
replace ([CRIDGI], 'inactive','') AS [CRID],
```

and it worked, but I need to add more words than just inactive

Comment: What database are you using? Could the word appear more than once in the string? Could there be multiple words multiple times in one string? Give us some real-world before and after examples.

Comment: Does your database support replace with a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using nested replaces:

```
select replace(replace([CRIDGI], 'inactive', ''), 'active', '') AS [CRID]
```

Alas, SQL in general -- and most databases -- have pretty lousy string manipulation capabilities.  It is hard to do better than the nested replace, although your database might have some functionality that would help (such as Oracle and Postgres).

Comment: Be careful though, if your string is "radioactive" it will end up as "radio" which is not the intended action.  You may need to head into the wonderful world of regular expressions.  :-)  i.e. Only replace "active" with NULL if it is surrounded by spaces or if it occurs at the end of the line, etc.